# how to get repeated repeated parameters from request?

Tags: php

for example, if end of a request url is like `?id=1&id=abc`

in handler, when I use `$_GET[id]` it returns `abc` where as I want to first value, which is I think overwritten, is it possible to get first one with same names?

PS, I can't change names of params, some stupid 3rd party server is using them to hit me.

Comment: no. you need to change parameters name. no other possibility.

Comment: Why in the world do you need this? And what's the reason to pass the same parameter twice in the same request?

Comment: Why you want two same parametername? Make it two different or just append like `?id=1,abc`. And seperate them with comma ( , ).

Comment: why not change names. or,separated values. that is easy to handle.you are complicating yourself. also if you got both id how you are going to distinguish them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explaind you better change the request with unique names

For your task ... this work ... in **$get** will be your Request as

```
  <?php
     $string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
     $data = explode('&',$string);
     $get = array();
     if($data) {
         $paired = $data[0];
         $res = explode('=',$paired);
         if(count($res)==2 && !isset($get[$res[0]])) $get[$res[0]]=$res[1];
     }
     var_dump($get);
     die;
```

Comment: thanks :) what I did was

`$reqUrl =  explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        $reqUrl = explode("&", $reqUrl[1]);
        $reqUrl = explode("=", $reqUrl[0]);

        return $reqUrl[1];`

Answer (score 1):

If you have controle over the get variables. you can do the following. Just add `[]` to the name to make your variable an array.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['name'])){

    echo 'first item: ' . $_GET['name'][0] . '<br>';
    echo 'second item: ' . $_GET['name'][1] . '<br>';
}

?>

<form methode="GET">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="Mickey"><br>
    //---------------------------^ add [] in your form
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="Mouse"> <br><br>
    //---------------------------^ add [] in your form
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `$_GET['name'][0]` returns first character of second parameter :( .

Comment: Than you didn't add `[]` to the name in your form and you didn't make an array of your get variables. I edited my answer.

Comment: problem is , I don't have the form , data is coming from a 3 rd party site. I don't have control to params, what I did now , used `explode()`s to get my thing, but I'm not satisfied with that solution

Answer (score -1):

Better you can change the parameters or else you can try explode function with the input values you get

Comment: don't you think it must be a comment?